# Show product image before image in content

Tags: magento2

Could anyone help me to show product image before image in content with Magento v2?

My website load is not so bad but the image of products are load after images in content. Thus, visitors think that my website load slowly.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain your question in brief? You can also share your website link.

Comment: website might be  eatnmore.com

Comment: Not mate. It is beta.flyfood.vn

Answer (score 0):

My site use magento is beta.flyfood.vn

You can check that it show images in body content before product image